# Applying histeq function to 3x3 blocks

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I divided the cameraman.tif to 3x3 blocks and I want to apply histeq function to all of these 3x3 blocks
and trying to get a new image. I need a help with histogram equalization of these 3x3 blocks on MATLAB.

```
I = imread("cameraman.tif");
 
for i = 2:3:255
    for j = 2:3:255 
         B = I(i:i+2 , j:j+2);
         J = double(B);
       
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
fun = @(heq) histeq(heq.data)
b = blockproc(img,[3,3],fun);

figure, imshow(imtile([img b],[]));
```

[image: Results]